# How can I prove whether or not this short-circuits with a test?

Tags: c#

Consider the following expression:

```
if(!(A || B))
```

I'm not sure if this would short circuit in the same manner as

```
if(!A && !B)
```

Will it?

If so, how would I write a test to validate this myself?

Comment: @MattL. If the first expression is `true` then there's no need for the `||` to continue evaluation so it will short-circuit. https://dotnetfiddle.net/jS58eJ

Comment: @MattL. [The conditional-OR operator (`||`) does not always evaluate both sides](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-or-operator). "If the first operand evaluates to true, the second operand isn't evaluated."

Comment: @PeterDuniho, my response, as well as Joe Sewell's, was not to the OP, it was to a "Matt L" who made a comment that he subsequently deleted. He stated that the `||` operator always evaluates both sides and never short-circuits. That statement is incorrect.

Comment: @CraigW.: ah, I see. Missed the `'L'`.

Answer (score 3):

Write a test where `A` and `B` are methods that return a boolean and have some sort of side-effect (e.g. setting a property). Then your test could check that `A` set the property and `B` did not. If you don't want a formal *test* test you could just use something like .NET Fiddle.

Here's a simplified example of what you're trying to do.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/jS58eJ

Answer (score 1):

"Short-circuit" in this context just means you don't evaluate `B` when `A` is `true`. One easy way to test that is to make `B` a method, make `A` whatever you like as long as it evaluates to `true` and then see if the `B` method is called. You can observe a call to `B` by running the code in the debugger and setting a breakpoint, or by setting a flag in `B`, or by making it a console program and calling `Console.WriteLine("B method called")` in `B` or…

I hope that's enough for you to get the idea.

And, for the record, the two expressions should short-circuit in exactly the same way. I.e. when `A` is `true`, `B` is not evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Well when it comes to logic and a couple of variables, I like to use truth tables.

So to do that you would have:

[image]

If you were to do unit test assertions you could use the four combinations of A and B and test to see if both cases are equal.

To use unit testing in C# and Visual Studio, you right click the method you want to have tests for and select "Create Unit Tests" like so:

[image]

This will create an additional project just for unit tests.

In this case the method **IsEquivalent(a, b)** returns *true* or *false* depending on whether the statements in question are equivalent.

So looking at our unit test code you could fill in the test method like so:

```
[TestMethod()]
    public void IsEquivalentTest()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(Program.IsEquivalent(false, false));
        Assert.IsTrue(Program.IsEquivalent(false, true));
        Assert.IsTrue(Program.IsEquivalent(true, false));
        Assert.IsTrue(Program.IsEquivalent(true, true));
    }
```

This test method now *asserts* if the equivalency testing method returns **true** for every combination of inputs of **A** and **B**.

If it does then we know the statements are equivalent!

To run the test right-click and select "Run Tests".
This should open up the Test Explorer which should indicate that all of the assertions passed!

[image]

This coincides with the truth table.

Comment: NOTE: I misunderstood the question! Sorry about that. Nonetheless I will leave this answer up just in case it helps someone!